# tar command does not produce the .tar.gz file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I am trying to iterate in a loop, tar a couple of directories with each iteration and then compare the md5 sums of both of them. I notice that my first tar statement produces the tar files one level above the actual path of the directory. i.e. the statement:

```
tar -czvf ${folder_name}.tar.gz /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}
```

produces the `${folder_name}.tar.gz` in  `/tmp/psk1/` rather than `/tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/`

and the second tar statement:

```
tar -czvf ${folder_name}.tar.gz ${edge_base_dir}/wlossf$ENV/app/${folder_name}
```

doesn't produce the tar file at all. I can't find it even on one level above the actual path.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /haas/wlf/wlossf$ENV/app | while read rec; do
    echo $rec
    folder_path=`echo ${rec} | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}'`
    folder_name=`echo ${folder_path} | awk -F '/' '{print $6}'`

    if [ ! -z ${folder_name} ] && [ ! -z ${folder_path} ]; then

        hdfs dfs -get ${folder_path} /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/   

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Hadoop to local copy job Successful"
        else 
            echo "Hadoop to local copy job Failed"
        fi

        tar -czvf ${folder_name}.tar.gz /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}
        hadoop_md5=$(md5sum /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}.tar.gz)

        tar -czvf ${folder_name}.tar.gz ${edge_base_dir}/wlossf$ENV/app/${folder_name}
        edge_md5=$(md5sum ${edge_base_dir}/wlossf$ENV/app/${folder_name}.tar.gz)

        if [ ${hadoop_md5} == ${edge_md5} ]; then
            echo "${folder_name} is good"
        else
            echo "${folder_name} is bad"
        fi  
    fi      
    echo ${folder_name}
    echo ${folder_path}
done
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `tar` creates files in current folder, i.e., in `$(pwd)`.

Comment: @mouviciel, ...btw, consider using `$PWD` -- `$(pwd)` is spawning a subshell, which pays a (relatively) heavy performance cost compared to just spitting out a built-in variable's value.

Comment: As @mouviciel stated, tar is creating zip files relative to where you're script is running. You can either "cd" into the directory you want the files to be created within or preferably provide a specific directory in the command itself. `tar cvzf path/to/new/file.tar.gz /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}`

Comment: The only reason for a strange behavior is probably $folder_name contains slashes "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mouviciel said in the comments, `tar` by default creates the file in the current working directory.

Simply prefix the tar.gz file with the folder and it will create it where you want it:

```
tar -czvf /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}.tar.gz /tmp/psk1/hadoop_validation$ENV/${folder_name}
```

Note that as you will be creating the tar inside the same folder that you are archiving, you'll get a `file changed as we read it` warning as part of the output. Nothing to worry about.